# Obtener valor de un td por ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mysqli

Buenas un coordial saludos.

Tengo un problema al obtener el valor de en un td (html).

Requiero tener 2 valores, los tengo pero moemnto de pasarlo al php no me lo detecta.

Explico con la imagenes mejor.

Los dos valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La respuesta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pasemos al codigo:

Aca obtengo el ID :

```
echo "<td><div style='width:100px; text-align:center;'>".$row2['id_propuestas']."</div></td>";
```

Aca selecciono al diseñador.

```
echo "<option value='1' >Prueba 1</option>" ;
echo "<option value='2' >Prueba 2</option>" ;
```

El codigo js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
        var i ;

        for (i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
            $('#idusers' + i).change(function(){    
                var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
                var dataString = 'action='+ id;

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'img.php',
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(r){
                        $("#cambiouser").html(r);
                    } 
                });
            })      
        }
    });

    $("#table tr").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');    
        var value=$(this).find('div:first').html();
        //alert(value);
        //console.log(value);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'img.php',
            data: value,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#cambiouser').html();
            }
        });
    });
```

El archivo img.php :

```
$diseno = $_REQUEST['action'];
$id = $_REQUEST['value'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos funciones, una para cuando se hace clic en la fila y solo envías ID; otra para cuando se modifica el *select* y solo envías el valor correspondiente.

Necesitas solo una función que envíe los dos valores cuando se modifica el *select*; la otra función es solo para cambiar el estilo de la fila.

**Nota:** en `$('[id^="idusers"]')` el circunflejo `^` es para decirle a jQuery que busque los elementos que tienen el atributo *id* que *comienza con*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Encontrar todos los select y asignar evento onchange
    $('[id^="idusers"]').on('change', function() {
        // Obtener valor de select
        let action = $(this).val();
        // Encontrar ID, buscando primero TR y, desde ahí, contenido del div
        let id = $(this).closest('tr').find('div:first').text();
        // Crear cadena para enviar los dos datos
        let dataString = `action=${action}&id=${id}`;

        // Comprobar lo que se va a enviar
        console.log(dataString);
        /* ********* Elimina esta línea para ejecutar petición
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'img.php',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(r){
                $("#cambiouser").html(r);
            } 
        });
        // **** Elimina esta línea */
    });
    // Al hacer clic en la fila, solo cambiar estilo
    $('#table tr').on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');    
    });
});
```

```css
#table tr td {
    padding:5px 10px;
}
.selected {
    background:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cambiouser"></div>

<table id="table">
<tr>
  <td><div style='width:100px; text-align:center;'>1</div></td>
  <td><select id="idusers1">
    <option value='1' >Prueba 1</option>
    <option value='2' >Prueba 2</option>
  </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div style='width:100px; text-align:center;'>2</div></td>
  <td><select id="idusers2">
    <option value='1' >Prueba 1</option>
    <option value='2' >Prueba 2</option>
  </select></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comenté el código de la petición AJAX para poder probar aquí el funcionamiento.

Comment: Funciona a la perfeccion muchas gracias el resultado es el esperado como siempre es de mucha ayuda tu comentario.!

Disculpa el abuso puedo preguntarte algo por interno tengo una duda sobre otro tema sobre ajax y javascript y veo que sabe bastante del tema y puede que me des la idea.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya funcionado. Creo que aquí no hay mensajería privada, pero puedes usar los comentarios.